# Android: How to write array list of strings in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I need to write a simple collection where documents only contain an array list of strings.

```
usersBlocked
    -blockerID
         - usersBlockedList
               -userID1
               -....
               -userIDN
```

At this moment I'm able to update the list if the document already exist in this way: (for testing porpouses I wrote it by hand).

```
val reference = Firebase.firestore
            .collection("usersBlocked")
            .document(userIDBlocker)

reference.update("usersBlocked", FieldValue.arrayUnion(userIDToBlock))
            .addOnSuccessListener { Logger.d("Blocked") }
            .addOnFailureListener { Logger.d(it.localizedMessage) }
```

As I said, if the document exists, the update is correct, but when there is no document... I'm getting this error:

```
NOT_FOUND: No document to update: projects/xxxxxx/databases/(default)/documents/usersBlocked/2oLOYbG2z9gRC5VugchEP7ZPpy53
```

I assume that obviously not exist, but I don't know how to write Arrays in a document.

I saw how to save Maps, but is not what I need.

DB Structure:

[image]

Comment: Uploaded a image of the db @Ashish

Comment: please check my answer if any queries just comment down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to confirm that there is any document available with your current `userid`. Put condition like i have put. It will check whether id is available or not. If id is not available. Then it will generate new document at your usersBlocked with uid and store array.

```
val reference = Firebase.firestore
    .collection("usersBlocked")
    .document(userIDBlocker).get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                reference.update("usersBlocked", FieldValue.arrayUnion(userIDToBlock))
            } else {
                val userdetail = HashMap<String, Any>()
                var usersBlockedList = arrayListOf<String>()
                usersBlockedList.add(userIDToBlock)
                userdetail["usersBlocked"] = usersBlockedList
                Firebase.firestore.collection("usersBlocked").document(userIDBlocker).set(userdetail)
                        .addOnSuccessListener { success ->

                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                            Log.e("Data Failed", "To added because ${exception}")
                        }

            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.e("Exception", "${exception}")
        }
```

Comment: Worked perfect. The point I missed is where you created the hashmap to add the "param". Thanks! @Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.update(data)` with `.set(data, SetOptions.merge())`  - this will create the document is it's missing, and update it otherwise.

Data would be a map:

```
val data = mapOf(
    "usersBlocked" to FieldValue.arrayUnion(userIDToBlock)
)
```

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document